# ListView Activity logic

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in Android and I've been experiencing "Skipped xx frames" everytime I load up my activity which is a list of languages. I tried optimizing the listview following tutorials (applied recycling and viewHolder pattern) but still can't get rid of the issue.

**ListLanguagesActivity.java**

```
package com.experiment.woppi.demoapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListLanguagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;

    static String[] languagesCodes = {
            "english",
            "japanese",
            "korean",
            "spanish",
            "french",
            "portuguese",
            "german",
            "italian",
            "russian",
            "arabic",
            "chinese mandarin"
    };

    static int[] languagesImg = {

            R.drawable.flag_country_usa,
            R.drawable.flag_country_jpn,
            R.drawable.flag_country_kor,
            R.drawable.flag_country_esp,
            R.drawable.flag_country_fra,
            R.drawable.flag_country_prt,
            R.drawable.flag_country_deu,
            R.drawable.flag_country_ita,
            R.drawable.flag_country_rus,
            R.drawable.flag_country_sau,
            R.drawable.flag_country_chn
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_languages);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.languageListView);
        sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.languageSearchView);

        final LanguageListAdapter adapter = new LanguageListAdapter(this, getLanguages());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // on click of list item
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                LanguageList selected = (LanguageList) adapter.getItem(i);

                Intent intent = new Intent();

                // the selected item
                String selectedItemCode = String.valueOf(view.getTag(R.id.item_id));

                // set the data to be passed
                intent.putExtra("languageCode", selectedItemCode);
                intent.putExtra("languageName", selected.getName());
                intent.putExtra("languageImg", selected.getImg());

                // set the data to be passed
                //intent.setData(Uri.parse(selectedItem));
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                // end this activity
                finish();
            }
        });

        // on query search, perform custom filtering
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                // call the filter method, passing the query "s" arg
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<LanguageList> getLanguages() {
        ArrayList<LanguageList> languages = new ArrayList<LanguageList>();
        LanguageList lang;

        Resources res = getResources();
        String langName;
        String langNativeName;

        for(int i=0; i<languagesCodes.length; i++) {

            langName = getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(languagesCodes[i], "string", getPackageName()));
            langNativeName = getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(languagesCodes[i] + "_native", "string", getPackageName()));


            lang = new LanguageList(languagesCodes[i], langName, langNativeName, languagesImg[i]);
            languages.add(lang);
        }

        return languages;
    }
}
```

**LanguageListAdapter.java**

```
package com.experiment.woppi.demoapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LanguageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<LanguageList> languages;

    CustomFilter filter;
    ArrayList<LanguageList> filterList;

    public LanguageListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<LanguageList> languages) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.languages = languages;
        this.filterList = languages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return languages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return languages.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return languages.indexOf(getItem(i));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row = view;
        ListViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        // use the inflater only when creating stuff for the first time and initialize view holder
        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_languages, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ListViewHolder(row, "LANGUAGES");

            row.setTag(R.id.item_view_holder, viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) row.getTag(R.id.item_view_holder);
        }

        // set the values for the fields
        viewHolder.mainTextView.setText(languages.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.subTextView.setText(languages.get(i).getNativeName());
        viewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(languages.get(i).getImg());

        // add language code in tag attribute for back-end usage purposes
        row.setTag(R.id.item_id, languages.get(i).getId());

        return row;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filter == null) {
            filter = new CustomFilter();
        }

        return filter;
    }

    class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            // check if the user has typed a query in search bar
            if(charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {

                charSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();

                // holds the new filter
                ArrayList<LanguageList> filters = new ArrayList<LanguageList>();

                // get specific items
                for(int i=0; i<filterList.size(); i++) {

                    // create new list of matched items
                    if(filterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence) ||
                            filterList.get(i).getNativeName().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)) {

                        LanguageList lang = new LanguageList(filterList.get(i).getId(), filterList.get(i).getName(), filterList.get(i).getNativeName(), filterList.get(i).getImg());

                        filters.add(lang);
                    }

                    // prepare list items - filtered items
                    results.count = filters.size();
                    results.values = filters;
                }


            } else {
                // if no query, leave everything as-is
                // prepare list items - original item list
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            // update the list view items with the filtered results
            languages = (ArrayList<LanguageList>) filterResults.values;

            // refresh the list view with new changes
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**LanguageList.java**

```
package com.experiment.woppi.demoapp;

public class LanguageList {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String nativeName;
    private int img;

    public LanguageList(String id, String name, String nativeName, int img) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.nativeName = nativeName;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNativeName() {
        return nativeName;
    }

    public void setNativeName(String nativeName) {
        this.nativeName = nativeName;
    }

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

**activity_list_languages.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_another_sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.experiment.woppi.demoapp.ListLanguagesActivity">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/languageSearchView" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/languageListView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [Broken code](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/3650) is off-topic for this site. Please [follow the tour](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB this is already a working code I am asking for a code review. I didn't post this in SO since it's much more appropriate to post it here. I don't think there is one best answer in a codereview forum since it is a "review". I was just looking for inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the skip frame: if you run in an emulator, it is OK. Please check in the real device for better visualization.

About the code:

1. In the `LanguageList` class, the `img` variable name should change to `imgId`.
2. In the `CustomFilter` class, the `charSequence` in the function `performFiltering` should be `final`, and avoid changing the argument value. You also reuse the `TextUtils` to check the empty string.

   ```
   final upperCharSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();
   ```
3. Duplicated `filterList.get(i)` should assign an `LanguageList tmpLang = filterList.get(i)`, the same for `Resource res`.

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that getLanguages() is slow. Try to initialize with an empty list and then notify of data set changes when get full list is ready.